# How to convince Mojave to zip all files in the source folder?

Tags: macos, zip, finder, macos-mojave, user-folders

When zipping a folder (through right click →  compress folder ),  OSX Mojave silently skips some subfolders like "Assets" and "Build".

Is there a way to stop this and force OSX to include ALL files and subfolders in the given folder?

Comment: What do you mean *skips*? Are they absent in the compressed file after opening it?Are they hidden in the first place?

Comment: are they locked? Are their permissions different?

Comment: The folders are absent in the compressed file. Non of the missing folders are locked or hidden and their permissions are the same as the folders that are successfully included. That's a really strange one...